# Obtain object from overriden method

Tags: java, events, methods, jtable, listselectionlistener

```
public class Job_GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JobDTO jdto;

    public Job_GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

      private void menuEditJobActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            editJob.setVisible(true);
            //here I want to obtain the updated dto. 
        }

  } 


public class JobDTO extends BaseDTO {
//setters and getters

}


class ListDataUI { 

    private void initListeners() {
        summaryTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        summaryTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    final int selectedRowIndex = summaryTable.getSelectedRow();
                    if (selectedRowIndex != -1) {
                        BaseDTO dto = data.get(summaryTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRowIndex));
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I am not sure how to obtain the `BaseDTO` object `dto` to `menuEditJobActionPerformed` method so I can display all the values of the object. How do I pass this from `valueChanged` when event occurs? I'm simply using a table, when a row is selected, the dto state changes, need to pass this new state to the class Job_GUI actionperformed method

Answer (score 1):

Declare `dto` right after your `class GUI {` declaration.

That way it will have global scope so all your functions can see it.

```
class GUI {
  BaseDTO dto;

  private void menuEditJobActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        editJob.setVisible(true);
        //Now you can access "dto"
    }

  } 

class ListDataUI { 

    private void initListeners() {
        summaryTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        summaryTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    final int selectedRowIndex = summaryTable.getSelectedRow();
                    if (selectedRowIndex != -1) {
                        /*BaseDTO */dto = data.get(summaryTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRowIndex));
                        //not declaring a new object
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Can't OP make use of getter and setter methods?

Comment: @Smit No. In this situation they are pointless. Getters and setters are highly overused.

Comment: Using a setter would allow the OP to disable the associated menu item when the value is `null`.  Can't do this with a direct reference, not without introducing management code in the `ListDataUI` that doesn't belong there - IMHO